# Any room for code optimization for calculating the indices of array that corresponds to target sum in java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization

here is my code for getting the indices of array whose value's sum correspond to a given target value. currently in worst case it is O(N2) algorithm. any ways of improvements?

```
public class SumArrayTarget {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7 };
        System.out.println("The indices are "+ Arrays.toString(sum(arr, 12)));
    }

    public static int[] sum(int[] arr, int target) {
        int[] list = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int j = i+1;
            while (j < arr.length) {
                if (arr[i] + arr[j++] == target){
                    list[0]=i;
                    list[1]=j-1;
                    return list;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes there are always two numbers adding up to the required target. If there isn't, an empty list of indices {0,0} is returned. If this is the behaviour you require, then there is one improvement of complexity I can think of:

- Put your input array into a LinkedHashMap, mapping the number as key and its index as value. Takes O(n) time.
- Iterate over the map. For every item with key `n`:
- - See if there is an element in the map with key `target - n`, and if so, return an array with both keys in it. Takes expected O(1) time per element.
- If none of the elements of the map had a corresponding answer, return null or something to indicate there is no answer possible.

This puts the total runtime of the algorithm at expected O(n), but with horrible overhead. Your brute-force method is probably better for input arrays smaller than like a million.

If the question you're trying to answer also allows more than two indices as result, then you've got yourself the Integer Knapsack Problem. You can Google that, but it becomes a whole lot more complicated then!

Edit: Adding a sample implementation.

```
public static int[] sum(int[] arr,int target) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer>(arr.length);
    for(i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
        map.add(arr[i],i);
    }
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int n = entry.getValue();
        int index = entry.getKey();
        if(map.containsKey(target - n)) {
            return new int[] {index,map.get(target - n)};
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This might be O(n) on average, but I believe the worst case is still O(n*n) because of the possibility that all elements in the array have the same hash code.  I think that would make the problem equivalent to the same linear search he's already written.

Comment: Yes, the worst case is O(n*n) if all elements happen to collide. The hash code of integers is the int itself, though, so while the hash codes being equal won't matter (it'll just return the first of them), they can be assigned the same bucket if the load factor is low or with bad luck. This can be solved by using the TreeMap instead or a sorted array, resulting in O(n*log(n)) complexity and even worse overhead, but expected complexity says a lot too.

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong term, probably meant to say "hash index" or something like that, the index into the actual hash array.

Comment: (1) I'm not sure why you think O(n^2) would outperform O(n) for as much as a million items. For any amount more than a 100, I'd be surprised if O(n^2) outperforms O(n). (2) You could optimize as follows - for each item `n` in the input, check the map for `target - n`, then insert `n`. (3) Also, I'm not sure why you'd want a `LinkedHashMap` as opposed to a simple `HashMap`. Why do you want to iterate in order?

Comment: @Dukeling: I think linkedHashMap is better since it retains the order of input list and hence the indices returned correspond to the actual (correct) index of the starting list

Comment: @user1988876 The indices are already being stored as the value in the hash-map. A LinkedHashSet may have made sense, had there been functionality to get the index given an item.

Answer (score 0):

For a really large array `arr`, you could make it O(N log N) by sorting the array (which is O(N log N)), and then for each element `arr[i]`, do a binary search (**not best, see below**) on the rest of the array `arr[i+1]` to the last element looking for `target - arr[i]`.  Binary search is O(log N) so the entire algorithm would be O(N log N).  It would take a pretty large N to make this worthwhile--a lot larger than 7.

You can save a tiny bit of time in your current code: (1) If you compute `x = target - arr[i]` before you start the inner loop, and check `arr[j++] == x` inside the inner loop.  (2) If you know as a condition of the problem that all elements of `arr` are positive, then after you compute `x` as above, you can skip the inner loop entirely if `x <= 0`.

P.S. Make sure you know what you want to return if no result is found.  Your current code will return a 2-element array where both elements are 0.  That might be OK, since a caller can check for that, but it might be better to return `null`, especially since 0 is a valid value to return in one of the elements.

PPS.  After thinking about it a bit more, once you've sorted the array you shouldn't need to do binary searches to get the answer; you should be able to do it in O(N) time by having one index go forward through the array and another go backward.  Also, when you sort, you might want to create some small objects that include the value and the *original* index in `arr`, and sort those, so that you can put the original index in your return array.  Or just search `arr` for the two values you've found, which is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I would start from sorting the array.
2. But after that I would use the binary tree only for finding the pair to the first (now being current) element.
3. Even if the current element has not a correct pair, I would remember the place where I looked for it.
4. For the next element I would look for the pair starting from the place remembered, backward.
5. return to 2 until indices of the looked pair meet.

Comment: sorting the array gives different indices found at the end. I think sorting is a not an option. The list must be unmodified.

Comment: "sort" doesn't necessarily mean modifying the list.  You can sort an array and create a new array with the sorted values, without changing the old one.

Comment: @user1988876 Any limitations should be straightly given in the question. We are not telepaths here.

Comment: @user1988876 you could make the parallel array of indices, if you want to leave the array untouched.